# Dropwizard: return compressed result

Tags: java, dropwizard

I use dropwizard and want to return from my server compressed result. How can I do it?

I have following code:

```
@GET
@Timed
@UnitOfWork
public EntityResponse getOutput(@QueryParam(value = "encode") String encode,@Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(encode)) {
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip");
    }
    return EntityResponse.success("result string");
}
```

I use some rest client and when I test this endpoint I see `NO CONTENT` when `encode` parameter is not empty. Maybe I return response wrongly, can help me?

EDIT:
I tried to do request due Chrome and receive `This site can’t be reached ... might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do this manually. Just enable gzip comrpession in your Dropwizard Yaml and use that instead. If enabled, all requests with gzip in their `Accept-Content-Encoding` headers will automatically have their response entities encoded with gzip. See http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.1/docs/manual/configuration.html#gzip.

Also, you do not have to set the content encoding header manually either. Just add `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` as an annotation to your method.

You can now remove all the logic and parameters in your method that would have dealt with the headers and encoding.

Code:

```
@GET
@Timed
@UnitOfWork
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public EntityResponse getOutput() {
    return EntityResponse.success("result string");
}
```

Yaml (minimum config):

```
server:
  gzip:
    bufferSize: 8KiB
```

Comment: I know about this way, but I don't need to compress response if size is more than `minimumEntitySize` and `endode` url parameter is `false` in any case or something else..